# Difference between ViewFields and Include, in JSOM

Tags: client-object-model

I am working on a solution where I am using JSOM, I got confused on to the usage of Include in when you load the items collection, and usage of  to get which fields you want? What's the specific purpose of each one?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both `ViewFields` query option and [SP.ClientContext.load method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn168903(v=office.15).aspx) allows to control the columns returned in result. The main difference that `ViewFields` query option also includes system columns. From another hand [SP.ClientContext.load method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn168903(v=office.15).aspx) allows to specify the columns strictly that will be included in result.

### Example

**ViewFields query option**

The following query:

```
<View><Query></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name="FileRef" /></ViewFields></View>
```

in addition to `FileRef` field, the fields such as `ID`, `Modified`, `Editor` and some another will be included in result.

**SP.ClientContext.load method**

The following method demonstrates how to include *only* `FileRef` field in result:

```
ctx.load(items,'Include(FileRef)');
```

### References

[CAML and the Client Object Model](http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/2012/02/03/caml-and-the-client-object-model/)

Comment: Hi Vadim, Thanks for your reply, when I used them together, I had to populate also the ViewFields with my fields, otherwise they won't appear in the query if I only use Include in the load function, I am confused about that.

Comment: Richard, you are right,I missed it. To summarize: in order to select the list of specific fields both the ViewFields query option and fields names for SP.ClientContext.load method have to be specified.

Comment: I would disagree, only the view fields need to be specified, if you omit the Include, it will still work, so why the need of the Include if I use viewfields??

Comment: If you specify ViewFields option, then also columns specified in ViewFields plus system columns will be returned in result. If, in addition to ViewFields option, you specify columns to retrieve in Load  method, than only that columns will be returned in result.