# JSOM error while loading Managed metadata fields " Value does not fall within the expected range"

Tags: 2013, javascript, caml-query, managed-metadata, jsom

I am trying to fetch items of a particular view using JSOM using below code:

```
ListDataService.getItemsByCamlQueryUsingCSOM = function (listName, camlQuery, viewfields) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = context.get_web();
        var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
        var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
        query.set_viewXml(camlQuery);
        var items = list.getItems(query);

        var index = viewfields.indexOf("LinkTitle");
        if (index !== -1) {
            viewfields[index] = "Title";
        }
        context.load(items, "Include(" + viewfields.join() + ")");
        //context.load(items);
        context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            deferred.resolve(items);
        }, function (sender, args) {
            deferred.reject(args);
        });
        return deferred.promise();
    }
```

I get a strange behaviour that if my viewfields has any Managed metadata field, the executeQueryAsync is mostly failing with below error "**Value does not fall within the expected range**"

```
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldMap.GetColumnNumber(String strFieldName, Boolean bThrow)
↵   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.GetRawValue(String fieldname, Int32 iIndex, Boolean bThrow)
↵   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.GetValue(SPField fld, Int32 columnNumber, Boolean bRaw, Boolean bThrowException)
↵   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.GetValue(String strName, Boolean bThrowIfValueMissing, Boolean bThrowIfFieldMissing)
↵   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.GetFieldValue_Client(String fieldName)
↵   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.WriteAsJson(JsonWriter writer, Object obj, ClientObjectQuery objectQuery, ProxyContext proxyContext)
↵   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.WriteChildItems(JsonWriter writer, Object obj, ClientObjectQuery objectQuery, ProxyContext proxyContext)
↵   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.WriteAsJson(JsonWriter writer, Object obj, ClientObjectQuery objectQuery, ProxyContext proxyContext)
↵   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.WriteAsJsonWithMonitoredScope(JsonWriter writer, Object value, ClientObjectQuery objectQuery, ProxyContext proxyContext)
↵   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.WriteQueryResults(Object obj, ClientObjectQuery objQuery)
↵   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessQuery(XmlElement xe)
↵   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessOne(XmlElement xe)
↵   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessStatements(XmlNode xe)
↵   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.Process()
```

My viewfields has only 3 or 4 fields and I tried to hard code only the Managed metadata field in the Include statement and still it threw the same error.

Configuration of my site:

1. List is having 30+ columns
2. Listview Look up threshold is 8 for the web application.
3. Site Regional setting has Local set to English(South Africa) (PS: Setting
   it to English(US) did not make any difference.)

**Update**: Got this issue fixed by adding the viewfields in caml instead of **Include** .

Comment: Same behavior if you specify the viewfields in the caml instead of Include?

Comment: @AndersAune Thanks for your suggestion it works always when I add it as ViewFields in caml. Strange but works for now. Please write it as answer so that I can upvote and mark it as answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hidden fields connected to the managed metadata fields could be the culprit. If you have a look at Vadims answer in this [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/117207/difference-between-viewfields-and-include-in-jsom) he says:

> The main difference that ViewFields query option also includes system
>   columns.

So try using `<ViewFields />` in the CamlQuery instead of `Include`